# Create More Widget Holders Like Active Widgets and Inactive Widgets

Tags: widgets

I am wondering if it is possible to create other Widget Holding sections like Active Widgets and Inactive Widgets.  For instance, perhaps I would create a Media Widgets section and place all media related widgets in there.

Is this possible?  If so, how could I create the section and how would I place the widgets in there?

Thanks.

Comment: Very good Question! But also afraid that the Answer may be: no. Put your bets on the table, Ladies and Gents..!

Comment: agree this would be very neat.

Comment: +1 But please explain, what "media related"-Widgets are. Thanks.

Comment: I was just using media as a made up example.  The point is that I would like to categorize widgets into logical groups.  For instance, I could have Social Media related Widgets (Twitter, RSS feeds, etc.), link related widgets (Links, Menu Items, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Probably isn't considered "best practices" but it gets the job done.

**Here's what I did:** In my wp-admin/widgets.php,

After these lines,

```
// register the inactive_widgets area as sidebar
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Inactive Widgets'),
    'id' => 'wp_inactive_widgets',
    'class' => 'inactive-sidebar',
    'description' => __( 'Drag widgets here to remove them from the sidebar but keep their settings.' ),
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => '',
));
```

add this

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Media Widgets'),
    'id' => 'wp_inactive_widgets2',
    'class' => 'inactive-sidebars2',
    'description' => __( 'Drag widgets here to remove them from the sidebar but keep        their settings.' ),
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => '',
));
```

When you add your widgets to the new holder, they'll display all the way across like in my pic. Perhaps because no styling was done to this new holder. Anyway this is working for me, I logged out and back in and my widgets are still there.

As always, when changing themes, your "Media Widgets" will be moved to the "Inactive" holder if the new theme doesnt have the same sidebar setup as the previous one.

Comment: To be honest, I'm proud of myself for even attempting to answer this question. I took a shot in the dark and made a new discovery myself!

Comment: That's what I was looking for - thanks.  Any idea, though, how to make this change via the functions.php file?

Comment: Hmm..To copy all of that code from widgets.php to functions.php seems tedious. I could be wrong, but the admin widgets dont work the same as theme widgets. Lot more going on in widgets.php, from what I see. (looked in both files just now). I've given, probably, the easiest solution. Sorry,  haven't tried to add anything to functions, maybe someone else will but an upvote would be nice if my answer helped you at all. Thanx.

Comment: The point of using the functions.php file is so that I don't interact directly with the core files.  Either way, it's a good first step (and I added an upvote as a result) - thanks.

Comment: I understand. I wish I knew how to do it in functions too. The good thing about this is it isnt a serious change in core. Just an extra widget in the widgets.php file. I'll try to figure out a way to do it from functions but the setup is completely different. Glad I could help :) By the way, unless you're waiting for another answer, you can mark this one as accepted, since It does, in fact, answer your initial question (your initial question doesnt include functions.php).

Comment: If it's okay - I'm going to hold off on marking the question as answered to see if anyone can come up with a solution that doesn't touch core.

Comment: Ok thats fine. I hope someone comes up with one for you too. I'm prety happy with adding them from widgets.php, myself. All that matters for me is that I was able to do it and hopefully others will use my example.

Comment: Seems as if no one else is going to offer a non-core changing solution - so I've marked the question as answered - thanks again.

Comment: @user15927 Honestly, I dont think there is one. This is not a theme issue, it is a core issue so changes need to be made in core :( & thanx

Answer (score 0):

No need to hack the WordPress core for that, on your functions.php theme file, put this:

```
// register the inactive_widgets area as sidebar
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Inactive Widgets 2'),
    'id' => 'wp_inactive_widgets_2',
    'class' => 'inactive-sidebar',
    'description' => __( 'Drag widgets here to remove them from the sidebar but keep their settings.' ),
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => '',
));
```